# undefined reference to CLASS::function()

Tags: c++

So when I try to simply compile my code using "g++ Asg5.cpp" I receive the following error

> /tmp/cczhpSGO.o: In function 'main':
>
> Asg5.cpp:(.text+0x2fb): undefined reference to 'BinomialTree::insert(int)'
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

If anyone's wondering why I'm not using a makefile, my professor simply wants to type g++ <.cpp with main()> to compile..

Anyway here's my code I really appreciate the assistance!

Asg5.cpp

```
#include "BinomialTree.h"
#include "BinomialNode.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //input handling
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Incorrect Usage. \n Example: ./a.out <filename>" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    BinomialTree *tree = new BinomialTree(); 
    
    char *buffer;
    char *token;
    //read file into buffer.**************************************
    string input;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        string str;
        while(file.good())
        {
            getline(file,str);
            input += " " + str;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout << "File not found"<< endl;
        return 1;
    }
    file.close();
    
    int buf;
    stringstream ss(input);
    
    vector<int> tokens;

    while(ss >> buf)
    {
        tokens.push_back(buf);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
        tree->insert(tokens[i]);
    //end file reading *******************************************
    delete tree;
}
```

BinomialNode.h

```
#ifndef _BINOMIALNODE_H_
#define _BINOMIALNODE_H_
#include "BinomialTree.h"
class BinomialNode
{
    public: 
        int k;
        BinomialNode *children[20];
        int data;
        
        BinomialNode();
};
#endif
```

BinomialNode.cpp

```
class BinomialNode
{   
    BinomialNode::BinomialNode(int n)
    {   
        this->k = 0;
        this->data = n;
    }
}
```

BinomialTree.h

```
#ifndef _MULTIMAP_H_
#define _MULTIMAP_H_
#include "BinomialNode.h"

class BinomialTree
{
    public:
        BinomialNode * BQ[20];
        

        void insert(int n);
        void merge(BinomialNode *queue, BinomialNode *in, int k);
        void print(BinomialNode *root, int tab);
};
#endif
```

BinomialTree.cpp

```
#include "BinomialNode.h"
#include "BinomialTree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


class BinomialTree
{
    void BinomialTree::insert(int n)
    {
        BinomialNode *in = new BinomialNode(n);
        if(BQ[0] == NULL)
        {
            BQ[0] = in;
            return;
        }
        else
            merge(BQ[0], in, 0);
    }
    void BinomialTree::merge(BinomialNode *queue, BinomialNode *in, int k)
    {
        if(queue == NULL)
        {
            BQ[k] = in;
            return;
        }
        if(n == NULL)
        {
            BQ[k] = queue;
            return;
        }
        if(queue->data > in->data)
        {   
            merge(in, queue);
            return;
        }
        queue->k++;
        BinomialNode* temp[queue->k];
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < queue->k-1; i++)
            temp[i] = queue->children[i];
        temp[queue->k-1] = in;
        for(i = 0; i < queue->k; i++)
            queue->children[i] = temp[i];
        if(BQ[queue->k] == NULL)
        {
            BQ[queue->k] = queue;
            return;
        }
        else
            merge(queue, BQ[queue->k]);
    }
    void BinomialTree::print(BinomialNode *root, int tab)
    {
        if(root == NULL)
            return;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < tab*5; i++) cout << " ";
        cout << root->data << endl;
        for(i = 0; i < root->k; i++) print(root->children[i], tab+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed the most important part: how do you build it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cpp files shouldn't have Class in them. They should look more like:

BinomialNode.cpp

```
#include "BinomialNode.h"

BinomialNode::BinomialNode(int n) :
  k(0)
{
  data = n;
}
```

And of course the corollary for the much longer BinomialTree.cpp. Also, you should compile it with something like:

```
g++ BinomialTree.cpp BinomialNode.cpp Asg5.cpp -o asg5
```

Also you're going to run into a lot of other problems with you code. For instance:

```
BinomialNode * BQ[20];
```

I don't see BQ being initialized anywhere, which means you're pretty much guaranteed a seg fault if you were to run this. You need to initialize this or allocate it. Seeing lines like:

```
if(BQ[0] == NULL)
```

Makes me think you really wanted:

```
BinomialNode BQ[20];
```

Though you would still need to initialize it to all NULLs since you aren't guaranteed that will be full of NULLs when you run the program. Also, this is recursive and infinite and can't possibly work (in BinomialNode.h):

```
BinomialNode *children[20];
```

There are likely more issues with this code, but that wasn't your question, so I'll stop now!

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback! I'm still in the process of writing code, just figured I would tackle the compilation errors first.

Comment: Ha! Got a little carried away there. Did you make some progress at least with the first couple parts of my answer? You may want to write a much simpler 'template' program that compiles and then start adding the complexity of your real effort a little bit at a time to figure out where the rest of the issues are.

Comment: I did, in fact I decided to just scrap the .h files altogether and just include the cpp's (while I know it isn't good practice) since it's overall a simple program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile all the .cpp files into one program.  You're not using `BinomialTree.cpp` anywhere right now.  If your project requires that you simply type `g++ Asg5.cpp` then you need to `#include` your .cpp files or move their contents to your .h files.  But the normal solution would be to build all the .cpp files together, not just the one containing `main()`.